when have brokerages allowed covering a short by a long position that is exactly convertible to the short position (w/no additional margin)?
This question is a followup to this one.

Per US Federal regulation 12 CFR 220.12, in a US brokerage account, a short stock position must be covered by holding an offsetting long position of one of two types:

(1) 150 percent of the current market value of the security; or
(2) 100 percent of the current market value if a security exchangeable or convertible [to the shorted stock...] is held in the account.

(Here, "convertible" means in the sense, say, of a preferred stock that is convertible to a fixed number of common stock.)
For example, suppose I am short 100 common stock of company X.  With Option (1), I could cover the position by holding any asset (e.g. cash or stocks) worth 150% of the value of the short.  In common terminology, this option requires a 50% margin.
In contrast, with Option (2), it would be enough to hold 1 preferred share of company X, provided that the preferred share is convertible on demand to 100 common shares.
With Option (2), I need no additional margin.
Question

When, if ever, have any North American brokerages allowed Option (2), covering a short by holding a long position that is convertible to the short position, with no (or little) additional margin?

Answers to the preceding question pointed out that Option (2) seems to be legal, but left open whether any brokerages have ever allowed it.
The current policies of the (three large US) brokerages that I've contacted do not allow it.
For focus, we can restrict the time period in question to the current century (post 2000), although I am also interested in the period before that.  According to an acquaintance, at least one small Canadian brokerage allowed this (with some associated fees) around 1990-2000.  The acquaintance also suggested that Option (2) may be used (and have been used) directly by institutions, e.g. market-makers, while no longer being available to the general public.
Motivation
One motivation is that the extent to which traders can use Option 2 affects their available trading strategies, so affects how prices of convertible shares tend to relate to the shares they can be converted to.

I see, thank you for the clarification. I will amend the question to try to make it more likely to be useful in the future as well, for readers who wonder to what extent the practice is possible.  To some extent, historical practice is likely to predict current and future practices.

Better, thank you. I am not convinced it actually has any real significance for current investment strategy, but this is an area of investing that I have little knowledge of.

Just curious: why would you want to do this?

See e.g. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/convertible-hedge.asp .
